# C++ Tricky Const Reference Exam Task?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I was exercising for my Exam coming up soon and there is a tricky question:

The question is:

> Whats wrong with the code and how would it be correct?
>
> ```
> const long limit = 1000L;
> long &ref = limit;
> ```

Now I typed it as C++ code and found out that the reference (&) was the mistake at this code sample, so writing long **ref = limit** solves it. However I would like to know why this solves the problem. Why is the
code above wrong?

Comment: Considering the variable is called `ref`, your solution is probably not the correct one. Hint: it has to do with the fact that `limit` is `const`.

Comment: How would it be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial code attempts to create a non-const reference to a `const` variable, which isn't allowed. Since a reference refers to the original variable, assigning to `ref` would (attempt to) modify the value of `limit`, which isn't allowed, because `limit` is `const`.

The second creates a variable, and initializes it with the value from the const variable.

You could also create reference to const: `long const &cref = limit;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Whats wrong with the code and how would it be correct?

const long limit = 1000L;
long &ref = limit;
```

Take the example one step further:

```
ref = 1001L; // ooops! we just changed the value of limit
```

Assigning a value to a reference modifies the original variable, which (in this case) is const. The compiler doesn't let you create a non-const a reference to a const value, to avoid this possibility.

Comment: true const should remain const and not being changable via reference. Nice extension to the answer above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be:

- the code is ill-formed because it tries to long& can not be intialized with a const object, it reauires lvalue of type long.
- The simplest fix is to delete that line, beyond that you must provide information on its goal, for that I can suggest